# How do i shorten a pandas data frame based by the dates in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this data frame that has many columns, but I'm only interested in the data spanning from say 01/01/2009-01/01/2019 so I want to keep all the data in that range and get rid of everything else

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `date column` name as `date_column`

```
df_new = df[(df['date_column'] > '01/01/2009') & (df['date_column'] <= '01/01/2019')]
print(df_new)
```

Comment: This also assumes that the column is already converted to datetime type. If not, you have to use "to_datetime" function from pandas.

Comment: yes, True!.....

Answer (score 0):

If they're correctly formatted:

```
df_new = df[df['date_col'].between('2009-01-01', '2019-01-01')]
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work no for any date format, dd-mm-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd

```
df[(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year >= 2009) & (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year <= 2019)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).